# Ansible: How to increment IP address?

Tags: yaml, ip-address, jinja2, ansible

I am passing a variable to Ansible with `--extra-vars "lan=10.10.10.1"`.

I now need to increment this IPaddress so that the last octet is `.2` so it will equal `10.10.10.2`.

How would this be achieved in Ansible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one line:

```
- set_fact: new_ip="{{ lan | regex_replace('(^.*\.).*$', '\\1') }}{{lan.split('.')[3] | int + 1 }}"
```

How does it work?

```
  tasks:
  - name: Echo the passed IP
    debug: var={{lan}}

  - name: Extract the last octet, increment it and store it
    set_fact: octet={{lan.split('.')[3] | int + 1 }}
  - debug: var=octet

  - name: Append the incremented octet to the first 3 octets
    set_fact: new_ip="{{ lan | regex_replace('(^.*\.).*$', '\\1') }}{{octet}}"
  - debug: var=new_ip
```

Output

```
TASK: [Echo the passed IP] ****************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "127.0.0.1": "{{ 127.0.0.1 }}"
}
TASK: [Extract the last octet, increment it and store it] *********************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {"ansible_facts": {"octet": "2"}}

TASK: [debug var=octet] *******************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "octet": "2"
}
TASK: [Append the incremented octet to the first 3 octets] ********************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {"ansible_facts": {"new_ip": "127.0.0.2"}}

TASK: [debug var=new_ip] ******************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "new_ip": "127.0.0.2"
}
```

Comment: Thanks again helloV.

Answer (score 11):

As of Ansible 2.7 this can be done using [IP Math](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html#ip-math):

```
{{ lan | ipmath(1) }}
```

Comment: Great, beaware that `ipmath` requires python `netaddr` package on the Ansible/control side.

Answer (score 3):

## Before Ansible 2.7

Using the [`ipaddr` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html#ip-address-conversion):

```
{{ ((lan | ipaddr('int')) + 1) | ipaddr }}
```

Be careful with the operator precedence of Jinja2, it's quite funky.

## Ansible 2.7+

Use [ipmath() filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html#ip-math). See [the answer by Lars Francke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52896573/).

Comment: Just to note that if you're using this with a CIDR style address (e.g. "192.0.2.0/24" and you want to increment that by 1, you need to first get the network address - like this: 
`- set_fact:\n    router_ip: "{{ (( lan | ipaddr('subnet') | ipaddr('int') ) + 1) | ipaddr }}"`

Comment: There is now an easier solution as per Ansible 2.7. See my answer here.
IP Math is now supported: `ipmath(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the [ipaddr filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html)

Comment: I will have a look at this as I may need this for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful, if you want to do this with a subnet.

```
- name: Give IP addresses sequentially from a subnet
  debug:
     msg: "{{ '10.10.1.48/28' | next_nth_usable(loop_index) }}" 
  loop: "{{ list }}"
  loop_control:
     index_var: loop_index
```

Please do not forget to install "***netaddr***" Python library before running the playbook via:

```
pip install netaddr
```

Lastly, please bear in mind that ***index_var*** starts from **0**, so if you want to start it from the 1st IP address, switch the msg line with:

```
msg: "{{ '10.10.1.48/28' | next_nth_usable(loop_index |int + 1) }}"
```