# Ansible: Loop through string and replace it in a file on each host for 1:1 mapping

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I know this might be simple question but somehow it's not working for me. I am not sure where i am making mistake.

I have a file called `/tmp/myfile` on all the hosts and has a string called `my_ip` on that file.

I need to:

1. Replace `my_ip` with unique IP addresses mentioned in `ip_addresses` field from `hosts.yaml` (inventory) file.
2. The host and IP mapping should be sequential. Like `abcde` must get string `192.168.1.2` as replacement in `/tmp/myfile` and so on.

So far, I tried the following:

Inventory file:

```ini
[hosts]
abcde ansible_host=192.168.1.102
pqrst ansible_host=192.168.1.103
xyzwa ansible_host=192.168.1.104
 
[ip_addresses]
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
```

Ansible task:

```yaml
---
    - name: Assign IP addresses to hosts
      hosts: hosts
      gather_facts: false
      tasks:
        - name: Assign IP addresses
          replace:
            path: /tmp/myfile
            regexp: 'my_ip'
            replace: "{{ item }}"
          with_items: "{{ ip_addresses }}"
          when: "'{{ inventory_hostname }}' in group_names"
      vars:
        ip_addresses: "{{ groups['ip_addresses'] }}"
```

But it loops through and assigns each IP to every host and eventually all hosts get the last IP from the `ip_addresses`.

Can someone please help?

P.S.: I don't want to define those variables into playbook. Also, can't use "template" as remote file `/tmp/myfile` will have different contents on all hosts but will have `my_ip` string in common.

Comment: If you want a `1:1` mapping, what prevents you to define the IP in the variables of the corresponding host: `abcde ansible_host=192.168.1.102 new_ip=192.168.1.2`; then use them in your template: `replace: "{{ new_ip }}"`?

Comment: Thank you for reply. 
No, I don't want to define it that way. 
I have actually 100+ servers and I need to assign subnet IPs to each of them.

Comment: Currently your given description and example data set looks for me like `new_ip = .10x - 100`. Is that the case? In other words, couldn't the IP just become calculated? Then, there would be no need for mapping lists. If not, can you provide more details?

Comment: I am not good in networking. So, not sure how you calculate IP in ansible (like generate next IP numbers). It would be just easier if I can get any help on looping through the ips listed in inventory file.

Comment: Actually, I am going to accept  the answer provided by @β.εηοιτ.βε .
It works that way. Even though I was thinking of separating hosts and IPs in inventory file, this still is okay. 
Thank you.. Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According your given description and example data set it looks for me like `new_ip = .10x - 100` and regarding your comment

> *How to calculate IP in Ansible (like generate next IP numbers)?*

a minimal example

**`inventory.ini`**

```ini
[test]
test01.example.com ansible_host=192.0.2.101
test02.example.com ansible_host=192.0.2.102
test03.example.com ansible_host=192.0.2.103
```

**`playbook.yml`**

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Show IP from inventory
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_host }}"

  - name: Calculate new IP
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_host | ipmath(-100) }}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show IP from inventory] ******
ok: [test01.example.com] =>
  msg: 192.0.2.101
ok: [test02.example.com] =>
  msg: 192.0.2.102
ok: [test03.example.com] =>
  msg: 192.0.2.103

TASK [Calculate new IP] ************
ok: [test02.example.com] =>
  msg: 192.0.2.2
ok: [test03.example.com] =>
  msg: 192.0.2.3
ok: [test01.example.com] =>
  msg: 192.0.2.1
```

> *It would be just easier ... looping through the IPs listed in inventory file.*

As you can see from output of the task `Calculate new IP` you can't depend on the order and would need to introduce an index and logic to hold both "lists" in sync or create a relation between them in an other way. That's something you would also achieve by using the from @β.εηοιτ.βε mentioned inventory file.

```ini
[test]
test01.example.com ansible_host=192.0.2.101 new_ip=192.0.2.1
test02.example.com ansible_host=192.0.2.102 new_ip=192.0.2.2
test03.example.com ansible_host=192.0.2.103 new_ip=192.0.2.3
```

**Further Documentation and Similar Q&A**

- [`ipaddr` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html) and [IP Math](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html)
- [Ansible: How to increment IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52896573/6771046)